# Updating angular code dynamically when conditions are met in nodejs code

Tags: node.js, angular, file, package.json

I was looking for something that can update the code automatically on certain conditions. It is similar to how the new dependencies are added to the **package.json** file, when we do an npm install.
How to make it possible ?

***Explaining Further*** - When I run a command (in node), I have some code in some other folder (Angular)- the command will update the code like for example inserting new imports.

Comment: You may want to look into creating some custom schematics for the Angular CLI. Here's a blog that discusses how the schematics work: https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Angular CLI +1.7 and update all dependency package you can use `ng upadte`

> running the ‘update’ command will check for changes in the auto
>   generated files that come with angular projects out-of-the-box and you
>   be ask if you want to overwrite the existing with the new. You will
>   also be prompted to choose from four options, y(yes), n(no),
>   d(difference) and h(help). Choose with discretion.

Comment: Here I just gave example of package.json file ! I know that cli will update it. The question is how does it updates. That technique i want to use so that I can update my angular code on running command from node !